# ppp stopped working on Fedora 28

Tags: fedora, ppp, pppd

Had no problems with `ppp`. Ran and update and it stopped working.

My setup:

```
Lenovo T470s with Fedora 28, Linux user-fedora 4.18.13-200.fc28.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Oct 10 17:29:59 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
custom board with Linux custom-board-0 4.14.0-xilinx-v2018.2 #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Sep 24 12:55:51 PDT 2018 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Command to run `ppp` on Fedora 28

```
sudo pppd -detach local debug noauth passive xonxoff lock dump 192.168.10.100:192.168.10.1 /dev/ttyUSB0 9600`
```

Command to run `ppp` on custom board

```
pppd -detach persist debug local noauth passive xonxoff lock dump 192.168.10.1:192.168.10.100 /dev/ttyS0 9600
```

Output of `ppp` on Fedora after command execution

```
pppd options in effect:
debug           # (from command line)
-detach         # (from command line)
dump            # (from command line)
noauth          # (from command line)
/dev/ttyUSB0            # (from command line)
9600            # (from command line)
lock            # (from command line)
xonxoff         # (from command line)
local           # (from command line)
passive         # (from command line)
192.168.10.100:192.168.10.1             # (from command line)
using channel 16
Using interface ppp0
Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/ttyUSB0
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <magic 0x1aa6d871> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <magic 0x1aa6d871> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <magic 0x1aa6d871> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <magic 0x1aa6d871> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <magic 0x1aa6d871> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <magic 0x1aa6d871> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <magic 0x1aa6d871> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <magic 0x1aa6d871> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <magic 0x1aa6d871> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <magic 0x1aa6d871> <pcomp> <accomp>]
LCP: timeout sending Config-Requests
```

Output of `ppp` on custom board after command execution

```
pppd options in effect:
debug           # (from command line)
-detach         # (from command line)
persist         # (from command line)
dump            # (from command line)
noauth          # (from command line)
/dev/ttyS0              # (from command line)
9600            # (from command line)
lock            # (from command line)
xonxoff         # (from command line)
local           # (from command line)
passive         # (from command line)
192.168.10.1:192.168.10.100             # (from command line)
using channel 11
Using interface ppp0
Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/ttyS0
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <magic 0x4b51417a> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <magic 0x4b51417a> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <magic 0x4b51417a> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <magic 0x4b51417a> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <magic 0x4b51417a> <pcomp> <accomp>]
rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <magic 0x1aa6d871> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfAck id=0x1 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <magic 0x1aa6d871> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <magic 0x4b51417a> <pcomp> <accomp>]
rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <magic 0x1aa6d871> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfAck id=0x1 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <magic 0x1aa6d871> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <magic 0x4b51417a> <pcomp> <accomp>]
rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <magic 0x1aa6d871> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfAck id=0x1 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <magic 0x1aa6d871> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <magic 0x4b51417a> <pcomp> <accomp>]
rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <magic 0x1aa6d871> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfAck id=0x1 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <magic 0x1aa6d871> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <magic 0x4b51417a> <pcomp> <accomp>]
rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <magic 0x1aa6d871> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfAck id=0x1 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <magic 0x1aa6d871> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <magic 0x4b51417a> <pcomp> <accomp>]
rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <magic 0x1aa6d871> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfAck id=0x1 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <magic 0x1aa6d871> <pcomp> <accomp>]
LCP: timeout sending Config-Requests
rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <magic 0x1aa6d871> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x2 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <magic 0x82da991a> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfAck id=0x1 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <magic 0x1aa6d871> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x2 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <magic 0x82da991a> <pcomp> <accomp>]
rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <magic 0x1aa6d871> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfAck id=0x1 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <magic 0x1aa6d871> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x2 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <magic 0x82da991a> <pcomp> <accomp>]
rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <magic 0x1aa6d871> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfAck id=0x1 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <magic 0x1aa6d871> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x2 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <magic 0x82da991a> <pcomp> <accomp>]
rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <magic 0x1aa6d871> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfAck id=0x1 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <magic 0x1aa6d871> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x2 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <magic 0x82da991a> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x2 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <magic 0x82da991a> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x2 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <magic 0x82da991a> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x2 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <magic 0x82da991a> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x2 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <magic 0x82da991a> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x2 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <magic 0x82da991a> <pcomp> <accomp>]
LCP: timeout sending Config-Requests
```

It looks like Fedora is sending LCP packets and Custom Board is receiving them, and Custom Board is sending LCP packets but Fedora is not receiving them.

Does anyone know what could be the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: Are you sure your serial cable is working, and not broken or loose?

Comment: @MichaelHampton It is working. To make sure it is working, I used minicom on both machines data is being sent with no issues.

Comment: You get data in both directions with minicom?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a day of debugging it turned out to be an issue with the custom board. One of the pins in the connector turned out to be electrically damaged. So it is not an issue with Fedora or PPP, it is an issue with the hardware connector. Thank you everyone for looking into it.